# Can't add tinymce to Extjs4 with his plugins

Tags: tinymce, extjs4

I addes the plugin tinymce how it is explained in this link:
http://harrydeluxe.github.io/extjs-ux/example/form/tinymce_tab.js
but I can't add tinymce plugins and toolbar or buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I added a file : 'Ext.ux.panel.UploadPanle.js' and after put it as extend on the view where I wanted to implement the tinymce.
in that file, you can find how the variable used to put to implement plugins.